# Node substitui Nginx? Alguém me explica essa arquitetura?

Tags: node.js, nginx

Estava lendo um [artigo](http://cdn.nginx.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/The_Dawn_Of_Enterprise_JavaScript.pdf?mkt_tok=eyJpIjoiWWpjME9UWmxOVGMwTkRNdyIsInQiOiJDT0sxdElBejlyV1h3N3ZhbXVJMjlYUVVHblwvRTN0dm83b1JzN3U1cHkrVmFjRytnTlwvSitiQURselMxWW5RV1hBT2Q0MUtVbFlBZEJidGsyQVRwY04ySlAzeG1TTVZTeWlqd0hMYklHbk9nPSJ9) sobre o "amanhecer" das empresas JavaScript.
O "amanhecer" no sentido de que as coisas só estão começando. Ou seja, segundo o autor, o futuro é do JavaScript, com o NodeJS, e as empresas mais cedo ou mais tarde terão que substituir suas tecnologias .net e java por uma solução de processamento cliente.

E para ir mais além o autor mistura nessa arquitetura o Nginx interagindo com o Node.

Então vem minha dúvida:

Se a grande jogada do Node é a conexão não obstrutiva com o servidor, qual seria então a vantagem dele sobre o NginX já que este último também permite conexões não obstrutivas?

Abaixo, na foto, o autor coloca o Nginx como a primeira camada de acesso e esse fazendo consultas ao Node. Fiquei confuso.

Alguém explica essa arquitetura também.

[Tecnologias disruptivas](http://www.mckinsey.com/business-functions/business-technology/our-insights/disruptive-technologies) (não sei se essa é a boa palavra em português) estão a caminho, isso é certo, e a tendência do do grande fluxo de dados tanto entrando como saindo (atrvés de APIs) também é algo certo.

Mas não consigo enxergar o que faz o NodeJS indispensável, com o Nginx disponível.

Comment: Tá igual o papo que eu ouço faz uns 10 anos de que a web ia substituir o desktop. Falei que era besteira, vejo hoje que é realmente besteira (não que as pessoas não estejam tentando insistentemente, o fato é que o resultado é sempre muito ruim por mais que elas teimem). Isso que você comentou é mais uma dessas modas, pois tudo que o node tem, qualquer linguagem séria tinha no passado. O que é novidade pra molecada da web no Node, por exemplo não impressiona muito quem já programava faz um tempo. NOTA: Não é uma crítica ao produto, e sim ao pensamento de que todo mundo tem que mudar de "moda".

Comment: Pois é. Eu sou desenvolvedor back-end. Estou substituindo apache por nginx devido a alguns resultados de benchmarking. Mas continuo no php.  Estou tentando encontrar um motivo para substituir minha velha arquitetura para NodeJs. E não estou achando.Eu concordo 100%. Não corro atras de moda. Mas quro saber se tem algo que nao estou vendo.

Comment: Justamente, e se mudar, pra que Node.js? Por que não C# ou outras tantas? Não estou dizendo que essa é melhor do que aquela, nem o contrário. Só quero dizer que tem e já tinha muita coisa no mercado antes do Node.js, e vai continuar tendo. Me lembrei do furor do Ruby on Rails, os caras falavam que ia acabar com as outras tecnologias Web, e hoje mal vejo.

Comment: @zwitterion Em termos de performance, outras linguagens (Go, Java, C#, JavaScript/Node.js) geralmente trazem resultados mais satisfatórios e maior escalabilidade. Se eu fosse escolher hoje, focaria em Go que além de trazem uma performance melhor que ambos Node.js e PHP, ainda possui um consumo de memória ridiculamente baixo (e uma sintaxe mais produtiva que um C ou C++, por exemplo).

Comment: @Kazzkiq Justamente, tem mil motivos diferentes pra cada um escolher outra opção. Eu uso PHP pra bastante coisa, mesmo PHP sendo uma coisa extremamente mal feita. Para coisas que preciso de mais performance e estabilidade, uso outra linguagem no mesmo servidor (que não é nenhuma das mencionadas) e não iria pro Node.js, que já nasceu mais limitado que o que eu uso hoje. Então, não dá pra definir qual é o caminho, cada um tem que por todos os pesos na balança de acordo com sua realidade. Creio que apesar de uma discussão interessante, pro formato do site eu acho complicada a pergunta.

Comment: @Bacco, fiz um update na minha pergunta.

Comment: @zwitterion até tinha editado o comentário anterior sobre isso. Eu acho uma discussão interessante, mas acho que pro formato Q&A nao funciona legal. Se pegar um dia movimentado no chat da rede dá pra ir longe com o assunto (acho que ficou muito ampla e corre o risco de virar debate opinativo, pra falar bem a verdade).

Comment: @Kazzkiq, tbm pensei nisso. Memoria hoje em dia, é algo que não assusta tanto. 2Semanas atrás eu estava fazendo um trabalho num computador com 128G de memoria RAM e 31 processadores. Isso é algo tangível a aceitável hoje em dia.  Quando a performnca, vc já viu o benchmarking do php7? hega a ser até 40%-50% melhor do que as linguagens tradicionais. http://www.zend.com/en/resources/php7_infographic

Comment: @Bacco esse debate deveria ser feito onde? Tbm acho que pode ser barrada, mas é um tópico que não deveria estar de fora de uma comunidade de programadores. Afinal estamos todos vivendo momentos de dúvidas e correr atraz de modismo é a pior coisa que existe. Temos que ter argmentos solidos para decidirmos uma arquiteura e excluirmos outra.

Comment: @zwitterion essa comparação dos caras foi feita só com linguagem de script. Não que eu ache "injusto", pq PHP é basicamente uma linguagem de script, que o pessoal inventou de usar de outras maneiras, mas se puser qualquer linguagem compilada (ou mesmo outras baseadas em runtime intermediário) perto, o gráfico fica bem menos atraente pro PHP.

Comment: Obrigado pelo *link*. Ficarei atento a tudo que essa empresa diz. Acho que nunca tinha visto algo com ar tão sério falar tanta besteira junta. Tudo suposições tolas pra vender um produto. Não é só informação tendenciosa, é a ingenuidade do autor. Ele não entende nada do assunto e acredita em Sací Pererê. Node traz **zero** inovação. E o que fizeram em volta do Node, e não o Node em si, que deu certo é, não só copiável para outras tecnologias, mas já foi copiado, assim como tudo, inclusive o Node faz. Eu tirei a ilustração, já que lá está explicitamente proibindo o uso.

Comment: Ok @bigown, eu nem tinha percebido a proibição da publicação da foto. Entáo o seu comentário parece estar sintonizado com aminha impressão. Parece ser mesmo um modismo - mais do mesmo no final das contas.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Eu vou focar esta resposta na sua segunda pergunta, já que a primeira (*Node substitui NGINX?*) cai num campo mais opinativo.

## Sobre a arquitetura Node.js + NGINX

A abordagem de implantar um servidor de rede na frente dos outros servidores pode trazer algumas vantagens tanto em termos de segurança, quanto de performance, dependendo da arquitetura do seu sistema.

O conceito é relativamente simples: adiciona-se um servidor que fica responsável por receber e repassar as requisições recebidas de fora (servidor este que geralmente é chamado de **proxy reverso**), e é tarefa desse proxy reverso repassar estas requisições internamente para os outros servidores processarem as tarefas relacionadas.

Isso significa que os servidores que de fato rodam as tarefas nunca ficam diretamente expostos à rede externa. Toda requisição que chega até eles antes teve que passar pelo proxy reverso. Mas quais as vantagens disso?

#### Segurança

Servidores maduros e "calejados" durante anos de testes em ambiente real como o NGINX possuem inúmeros recursos embutidos que facilitam na hora de proteger o seu servidor contra possíveis ataques externos usando poucas linhas de configuração (os módulos [`http_limit_request`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html), [`http_limit_conn`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_conn_module.html) e [`client_header_timeout`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html?utm_source=mitigating-ddos-attacks-with-nginx-and-nginx-plus&utm_medium=blog#client_header_timeout) são alguns exemplos disso).

Além disso, adicionando um servidor focado exclusivamente para lidar com requisições de forma performática à frente dos seus outros servidores, permite que você tenha um possível aumento de estabilidade e segurança logo de cara, já que um servidor como o NGINX foi construído exclusivamente com esse propósito em mente (ao contrário do Node.js por exemplo, que tem um foco infinitamente mais abrangente e muitas vezes pode não ter sido otimizado especialmente para esta tarefa específica).

#### Separação de escopo

Assim como um martelo não serve para realizar todas as tarefas na construção de uma casa, um único servidor (ou linguagem) específico também pode não ser a melhor solução para todas as partes do seu sistema. Com um proxy reverso fica muito mais fácil receber as requisições e repassá-las de acordo com a tarefa requisitada.

Isso permite que você consiga uma maior modularidade na sua aplicação, de forma que cada servidor tenha um foco específico, exemplo:

- **Módulo em C**: Responsável pelo processamento de tarefas onde a performance é crucial,
- **Módulo em PHP**: Restante da aplicação, onde a produtividade é mais importante que a performance

Caso a sua aplicação fosse dividida nos módulos acima, usar um proxy reverso que redirecionasse as requisições para seus respectivos módulos deixaria o escopo muito bem separado e organizado.

#### Performance

Como dito antes, servidores como o NGINX foram construídos desde a primeira linha de código com performance e escalabilidade em mente. Esse tipo de servidor é focado exclusivamente em processar requisições de rede (inclusive com uma abordagem [*Event Driven*](https://www.nginx.com/blog/inside-nginx-how-we-designed-for-performance-scale/) semelhante à do Node.js), e não é de se admirar que cumpra esse papel extremamente bem. Isto também significa que as vezes pode ser muito mais vantajoso usar um servidor como esses para servir de porta de entrada para o seu sistema, do que uma outra solução mais nova e com um foco muito abrangente (como é o caso do Node.js). Aqui nós voltamos na questão do escopo: cada ferramenta tem um foco, e como o foco do NGINX é performance no processamento de requisições, não é de se admirar que ele sirva melhor esse propósito do que outras soluções sem o mesmo foco.

Outras respostas com maiores detalhes sobre as vantagens de se utilizar um proxy reverso à frente do Node.js podem ser encontradas aqui:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16770673

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9967887

Answer (score 2):

Não é bem por aí!

O Nginx foi criado antes que Node.js. Ngix foi criado por um russo em 2002 e é um proxy reverso, que trabalha orientado a processo ao invés de threads como Apache. Além disso ele tem um modelo onde criamos um Master Process, que controla diversos Worker process. Essa arquitetura é suportada por um mecanismo de loop de eventos, porém não em thread única como em Node.Js, mas com esse conceito de processos. Me lembra Fork de C em Unix! Bem, essas características ajudam aentender que Node.Js serve melhor ao propósito de processar o código JavaScript do lado do servidor e Nginx como proxy reverso fica uma ferrari! A Amzon usa nginx, bem como outros grades sites de alto volume de requisições simultãneas. Numa arquitetura distribuída, você coloca um Master Process do Nginx coordenado as requisições para vários worker process executando Node.Js. Isso é performance e escalabilidade.

Comment: Muito bom. Continuo aprendendo.

Answer (score 1):

Resumindo ao máximo: node.js é uma plataforma de desenvolvimento de software voltada preferencialmente para a internet, e preferencialmente para a web (protocolo http). Nginx é um servidor http.

Os dois produtos (são produtos de software) não são comparáveis. Querer compará-los é comparar alhos com bugalhos, laranjas com bananas.

Comment: Oi José, a minha intenção não é comparar nodeJs com NginX. A minha intenção é tentar enteder pq usar o NodeJs para se conectar a um banco de dados por exemplo, e criar uma página dinamicamente, se o PHP já faz isso? O argumento que tenho visto é que o node faz conecção não obstrutiva, mas o nginx tbm faz. A outra explicação que vejo muito é a economia de recursos, processador e memoria do servidor em um cenário de alta concorrência. Isso tbm é um argumento, que ao meu ver não justifica o uso do Node. Ter recursos de memória e processamento está ficando mais barato com o passar do tempo.

Comment: Eu acho que essa discussão toda não faz sentido. Node.js é (principalmente) uma plataforma para desenvolvimento web, assim como existem outras plataformas, como PHP que você citou, Java, C#, Python, Ruby, Perl, etc. O fato de Node.js utilizar "conexão não obstrutiva" (como você diz) é só um detalhe de implementação, não é isso que vai ser um fato determinante na escolha de Node.js em lugar de um framework Java,  ou PHP, ou Python, etc. E novamente repito, o escopo do Node.js é muito maior do que o escopo do nginx, então não faz sentido fazer comparações entre eles.

Answer (score -2):

O nginx faz exatamente a mesma coisa que o apache faz, Ele é simplesmente um servidor http que trabalha com o protocolo CGI "common gateway interface" que é usado em paginas dinâmicas, o trabalho do CGI é invocar um interpretador ou o sistema para executar um aplicativo web feito em qualquer linguagem de programação backend !

o nodeJS acredito ser uma plataforma que auxilia um programador JavaScript trabalhar no Backend.
se não me engano, Acredito que o nginx seja feito em node.